Dynamically inject HTML with Angular code, into existing DOM
I am using Bootstrap Tables in an Angular app. To render custom buttons in a cell, I have to write the HTML code from the Angular Component, defining the HTML as a string. However in this way, I can't bind component functions.
For instance, I want to add this HTML programmatically from the component code
elem.innerHTML = "<button (click)='myFunction(index)'>
                     Alert {{index}} 
                 </button>";

where myFunctionis a component function. This code will not work since it will be handled as static HTML.
I managed to solve this when I used old AngularJS. This is the working solution I adopted with AngularJS and Bootstrap Table.
/** function that renders the button */
const formatButton = function(row_element, index)
{
 var html = `<button onClick="angular.element(this).scope().myFunction(${index})">
                Alert ${index} 
            </button>`;
}

/** init, create the table */
function init(){
var table_columns:[
   {
    title:"Column 1",       // th name
    formatter: formatButton // render cells
   }];

jQuery("#table-id").bootstrapTable(
  {
   columns: table_columns,
   data:data
  });

}

/** function called by the button */
$scope.myFunction(index)
 { alert(index); }

this renders a table like this. clicking on buttons, will call $scope.myFunction() showing an alert with the row index
==============
|             |
|  Column 1   |
|             |
=============
|  Alert 0   |
--------------
|   Alert 1  |
_____________

In modern Angular, I don't have $scope, so I really don't know how to access to component function myFunction() from injected html, callable by simple onClick and not by (click)

Use renderer2 and add an event listener to the button.

You need to create the component for the button and then pass then object to the component as input.
Something like this,
{
        "type": "table",
         "props": [
            "COLSEP",
            "ROWSEP"
        ],
        "index": 1
        "function": {
                    "arguments": "index",
                    "body": "console.log(index)"
                }
           
        "htmlTemplate": "<table style=\"display: none; border-collapse: collapse;\" border=\"$BORDER\">$CONTENT</table>"
    }

this is a config, check how I stored the function in json.
In your Angular component, get this json and bind the function like this
this.function = new Function(value.arguments, value.body);
In your component's template there should be a button
<button (click)="callMe()" [innerHTML]="value.htmlTemplate"></button>

callMe() {
   this.function(value.index)
}

I understand this is a very short explaination. Comment if you don't understand anything.

I solved in this way. Please, comment my solution saying if it's suitable or have any down side.
These the steps:

put the HTML I'd like to inject, as a separate Component

    @Component({
      selector: 'alert-button',
      template: ` <button (click)="myFunction(index)">
                            Alert {{index}}
                    </button>   
                `,
    
    })
    export class AlertButton{
      @Input() index: string = '';
    
      constructor() 
      {}
    
      public myFunction(text:string)
       { alert(text); }  
    }


On the container Component, import some Refs.

import { ElementRef, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core';
import {AlertButton} from ...

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
              private _ViewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
             ) 
  {}


Inject the HTML as string. You can inject any HTML you like, later you will reference to it, and replace with the component. Write also the params you will need for the component.

function injectHtml(value)
{
  var html = ` <alert-button-placeholder index="${value}"></alert-button-placeholder >`;
  return html;
}


Once you injected all the HTML, replace it with real Angular components.

// render Angular components

// retrieve placeholders elements
var elements = (<HTMLElement>self.el.nativeElement).querySelectorAll('alert-button -placeholder');
for (let c in elements)
 {
  var element = elements[c]; 

  // create the angular component
  const component: ComponentRef <any> = self._ViewContainerRef.createComponent(CheckoutIdButton);

  // get attributes from the placeholder, and pass them to the component  
  var attrs = element.getAttributeNames();
  for(let a in attrs)
    {
     var attr_name = attrs[a]; // should be "index"
     component.instance[attr_name] = element.getAttribute(attr_name);
    }
  // get the HTML element from the component
  const new_element: HTMLElement = component.location.nativeElement;
  new_element.contentEditable = 'false';  
  // append the new element to the placeholder
  element.appendChild(new_element);
               }


